# Sharepoint Online web api returns 401 after logged In using angular

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online, adal

Am using Angular 4 application with Adal angular4 for connecting sharepoint online web api. I can able to view the user info which means I can able to login to the sharepoint online application. But after I could not able to get the list using the api.

```
const url = 'https://sitename/sites/applicationName/_api/lists/getbytitle(\'tenets\')/items';
const myHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.adalService.getCachedToken(environment.config.clientId),
  'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
});
return this.http.get(url, { headers: myHeaders }).subscribe(
  data => console.log(data),
  err => console.log(err),
  () => console.log('in complete')
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint Online is used to store the data and it can be used as a web api. We are integrating this web api to Angular application. Below steps are helps to integrate adal-angular4 with Angular7

Install latest version of Adal-angular using below the command,

```
npm install adal-angular4 –save
```

Add AdalService and AdalGurad in provider @app.module.ts

```
providers: [ AdalService, AdalGuard],
```

Set up the SharePoint configuration in src/environment/environment.ts file

Ex:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  config: {
    tenant: 'tenant-id,
    clientId: 'client-id',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/'
  }
};
```

Create a service and import the AdalService and create a private variable for AdalService inside the constructor. Initialize your SharePoint Online configuration in constructor()
Ex: Web.service.ts

```
import { AdalService } from 'adal-angular4';
constructor(private adalService: AdalService) {
    this.adalService.init(environment.config);
  }
```

Write below mentioned method inside the service 
Ex:

```
 handleWindowCallback() {
    this.adalService.handleWindowCallback();
  }
  login() {
    this.adalService.login();
  }
  logout() {
    this.adalService.logOut();
  }
  get authenticate() {
    return this.adalService.userInfo.authenticated;
  }
```

Once defined the above method, setup your login process in your login component. In general, after successful login, SharePoint will redirect to login component only, so we are validating the login and redirecting to a specific page.
Ex:

```
import { WebService } from '../web.service';
constructor(private webService: WebService) { }
ngOnInit() {
    this.webService.handleWindowCallback(); // this is to store the token to adal storage
    if (this.webService.authenticate) {
      this.router.navigate(['/', 'dashboard']);
    }
  }
login() {
    this.webService.login();
}
```

Add the below code inside auth.guard.ts to check whether the user is authenticated before every routing with the help of authenticate() method which is present inside the service,

```
constructor(private webService: WebService) { }
canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> |boolean{ 
      if (this.webService.authenticate) {
        return true;
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
```

Add the below mentioned codes inside the login component to call the service on every login and logout request,

```
login() {
     this.webService.login();
}
logout() {
     this.webService.logout();
}
```

Write the below method inside the service to make a request to the SharePoint using URL and to get the corresponding response by passing the title,

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';

getdata(listname): Observable<any> {
    const url = 'https://sitename.sharepoint.com/sites/application_name/_api/web/lists/
                 getByTitle(\'' + listname + '\')/items';
    return this.adalService.acquireToken('tenantid/tenant name')
           .flatMap(token => {
                    const headersParam = new HttpHeaders({
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token.toString()
                    });
                return this.http.get(url, { headers: headersParam });
            });
  }
```

Add the below mentioned method inside the component where you want to fetch and process the data.

```
getdata() {
    const listname = 'tenets';
    this.webService.getdata(listname).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
}
```

This method prints the value and title of the tenets list,